# Can changes in the order of the method parameters be called method overloading?

Tags: java, overloading

Please note that only order of the parameters are changed in below example. So my question is - Can we call below example is of method overloading?

```
public void show(String s, int a){
    System.out.println("Test.show(String, int)");
}
public void show(int s, String a){
    System.out.println("Test.show(int, String)");
}
```

Comment: signature changes, of course it is overloading.

Comment: Yes they are overloaded. You could have just checked it yourself. The compiler would give error in case of wrongly overloaded method.

Comment: Can? Yes. Should? Probably not.

Comment: @RohitJain I guess OP's question was not, if this is possible, but if `overloading` is the correct term for it, which Jon Skeet explained perfectly (once again)

Comment: @Juvanis just because the signature changes, this doesn't mean it's overloading. In fact, Java doesn't support return type overloading (and yet, the signature is changing).

Answer (score 12):

Yes, that's absolutely method overloading.

From [section 8.4.9 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.9):

> If two methods of a class (whether both declared in the same class, or both inherited by a class, or one declared and one inherited) have the same name but signatures that are not override-equivalent, then the method name is said to be overloaded.

"Override-equivalent" is described in [section 8.4.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.2):

> Two methods have the same signature if they have the same name and argument types.
>
> [ ... Details on "same argument types ... ]
>
> The signature of a method m1 is a subsignature of the signature of a method m2 if either:
>
> - m2 has the same signature as m1, or
> - the signature of m1 is the same as the erasure (§4.6) of the signature of m2.
>
> Two method signatures m1 and m2 are override-equivalent iff either m1 is a subsignature of m2 or m2 is a subsignature of m1.